# Can I reserve all rights of website non-code content despite putting complete website (code & content) on Github?

Tags: license-recommendation, website

I would like to publish my website on Github. However, I want to keep all copyrights/trademark rights for the non-code content (images, texts, logos etc.), while putting the source code under an open source license.

Is that possible? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: When you say "*keep all copyright rights*", what exactly do you mean?  Do you really mean you want to retain copyright, or do you mean that you want to prevent anyone else doing anything with your content?

Comment: I would like to prevent anyone else from doing anything with the content. The code should be freely usable under an open source license, though.

Comment: Have you read [this question on the licence grant implicit in publication on github](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1720/what-can-i-assume-if-a-publicly-published-project-has-no-license), and does it tell you what you want to know?

Comment: This question refers to the case where no license is available. However, I want to provide an open source license for the code and at the same time make sure that the content (images, logos, text etc.) cannot be reused freely.

Comment: Ah, I see; thank you; I tripped up on the ambiguity of the word *content*.  How about [this question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/7764/what-is-the-way-to-handle-a-project-that-is-a-mix-of-software-and-non-software-i), and in particular the OP's own answer.  In your case, you'd use a mix of a free licence (for the code) and "*all rights reserved*" (to the extent that GitHub allows it) for the non-code content.